# Shaving Of Pubic Hairs

Tags: halal-haram, taharah

I wanted to know, I shave my pubic hairs, I don't want to shave scrotum because I always cut it. will it be acceptable in Islam if I just shaved pubic hairs but not scrotum.

Answer (score 0):

**Bismillah Hir Rahmaan Nir Raheem**

**As Salaamu 3laykum,**

I hope you are doing well. So there are ahadith (Prophetic sayings) that tell us about shaving the pubic hair and to do so within 40 days time.

**Hadith #1**
ALLAH Messenger (ﷺ) said, "Five practices are characteristics of the Fitra: circumcision, shaving the pubic region, clipping the nails and cutting the moustaches short." (Bukhari in the book of dress)

**Hadith #2**
"[The Messenger of ALLAH (ﷺ)] fixed the time for us paring the mustache, trimming the fingernails, shaving the pubic hairs and plucking the underarm hairs - that we not leave it for more than forty days."
(Tirmidhi in the chapter of manners)
Sahih (Darussalam)

Now we need to define what is the pubic hair. According to Medical News Today (https://www.medicalnewstoday.com/articles/326578) it states: *"Pubic hair typically grows on the area between the belly button and the penis, but it may also develop on the penis and the testicles"*

**Conclusion**

So in my opinion we have to shave the hair above the penis (usually darker and bushier), on the penis and the scrotum as these are all considered pubic hair. I do not know if there are accounts from any other hadith or Sahabah (companions of the Prophet) that states the exact region. There maybe something out there but I do not know of it. What I have answered is based on what I have stated above.

**Have a nice day!**